# Line by line translation of subtitles

Tags: translation, dictionary, subtitles

I want to translate a text containing subtitles of a movie, but I need a line-by-line translation, preferably put side by side. If I can click on each word and see its translation or a corresponding word in the translation, that's even better. Machine learning quality of the translation will work for me.

That's for educational/learning purposes. I am looking for a piece of software, offline or online, both paid or free, that can do such a thing.

The language pair is Hebrew/English.

Comment: Google Translate will allow you to paste text for translation, and highlights the source when you point to the translation. Hebrew and English are both in Google's list.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Oh, I see. I will try it out with the context of my task in mind.